# What's the proof of this lemma by Hajnal about the randomized query complexity of monotone graph properties?

Tags: graph-theory, query-complexity

In [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01206357), Hajnal states the following lemma:

> Let $\mathscr{G}_{n, m}$ be the set of all bipartite graphs with $n$ vertices in the left part and $m$ vertices in the right part. Suppose $\mathscr{P} \subseteq \mathscr{G}_{n, m}$ is nontrivial, monotone, and invariant with respect to bipartite graph isomorphisms. Order the set of minimal graphs with property $\mathscr{P}$ lexicographically according to the sorted list of degrees of left vertices, and let $G$ be the first minimal graph with property $\mathscr{P}$ according to this order. Then the zero-error randomized query complexity of $\mathscr{P}$ is $\Omega(\frac{\Delta_L(G)}{\delta_L(G)} n)$, where $\Delta_L(G)$ is the maximum degree of any vertex in the left side of $G$ and $\delta_L(G)$ is the average degree of the vertices in the left side of $G$.

(In fact, Hajnal actually uses a slight extension of the above lemma.) The same lemma is also used by Gröger in [this other paper](http://www.inf.u-szeged.hu/actacybernetica/prevvols/10_3/10_3_119_127.pdf) and by Chakrabarti and Khot in [this other paper](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-48224-5_24). But I can't figure out the proof of Hajnal's lemma. Hajnal attributes the lemma to Yao and cites [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4568293/). But Yao's paper doesn't actually claim that lemma in that form.

Yao's paper does prove a closely related lemma. (Lemma 5 in Yao's paper, or equivalently Lemma 6 in [this journal version of Yao's paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002200009190003N).) By adapting the proof of the lemma in Yao's paper, I see how to prove Hajnal's lemma *under the extra assumption* that $\delta_L(G) \geq \Omega(1)$. I'm having trouble with the case that $\delta_L(G)$ is subconstant.

(I'll now assume that the reader is familiar with Yao's proof.) My understanding is that to prove Hajnal's lemma, the idea is to modify Yao's proof by essentially just replacing $\lambda(n)$ with $\delta_L(G)$ and $\mu(n)$ with $\Delta_L(G)$ everywhere. At a high level, with these modifications, Yao's reasoning still makes sense, and shows that to "discover enough missing edges", the query algorithm will need to make at least about $\frac{\Delta_L(G) - 4\delta_L(G)}{\lceil 4 \delta_L(G) \rceil} \cdot \frac{n}{2}$ queries.

The issue is that when $\delta_L(G)$ is subconstant, because of the ceiling operation, that lower bound is only $O(\Delta_L(G) n)$, which is much smaller than the bound $\frac{\Delta_L(G)}{\delta_L(G)} n$ that appears in Hajnal's lemma. (Concretely, the issue is that each set $T_i'$ needs to have an integer number of vertices in it.)

How can the proof be patched?

Comment: It looks like in all three papers that I mentioned (Hajnal, Gröger, and Chakrabarti-Khot), the authors only actually use the weaker bound $\Omega(\frac{\Delta_L(G)}{\lceil \delta_L(G) \rceil} n)$. There might be other papers that use this lemma, but I don't know of any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I sent an email to Péter Hajnal, and he kindly confirmed that the bound in the lemma should be $\Omega(\frac{\Delta_L(G)}{\lceil \delta_L(G) \rceil} n)$.